# Return statement in PHP functions

Tags: php, return

I'm having some problems with a **Return statement** in PHP. The thing is that, no matter what happend inside my function I always get a false value out of the function. I really think that is because of the Return statement because I try to use it in other functions and I don't get a diferent value.

```
public function valid_token ()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->token != $_SESSION['token'])
    {
        $this->errors[] = "Formulario incorrecto";
    }

return count($this->errors)? 0 : 1;
}
```

Out of this function I always get a **false** value (**0**). The same happends when i call:

```
public function valid_data () 
{
    if (empty($this->sectorName) || empty($this->sectorInfo) || empty($this->sectorCat))
    {
        $this->errors [] = "Datos incorrectos";
    }

return count($this->errors)? 0 : 1;
}
```

Of course, I call both functions when I have already sent the form and have set the token.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are just counting not checking,Try this

```
return count($this->errors) > 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: I even think count is lengthy.

Comment: You're wrong. count() returns a number. 0 evaluates to false, and any number different from 0 evaluates to true. And since count() doesn't return negative numbers, your check is unnecessary.

Comment: See this: http://ideone.com/BXnYiB

I'm sure there are another reasons.

Answer (score 0):

More simply,

```
return !$this->errors;
```